# mount raid gpt partition

Tags: linux, mount, raid

I have a raid system of 2tb that work on windows and I want to read on arch s.o.

After I have recognized and initialized fake raid with command

```
>> sudo dmraid -ay
```

this is result of command

```
>> sudo fdisk -l /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae

/dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae-part1      2048    1023999    1021952  499M Windows recovery environment
/dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae-part2   1024000    1228799     204800  100M EFI System
/dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae-part3   1228800    1261567      32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae-part4   1261568  204802047  203540480 97,1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae-part5 204802048 3906248703 3701446656  1,7T Microsoft basic data
```

I cannot mount /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae-part5

```
>> sudo mount /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae /mnt/varie/

/mnt/varie: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

-

```
>> sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae /mnt/varie/

The device '/dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
```

EDIT

```
>> sudo mount /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae-part5 /mnt/varie/

special device /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae-part5 does not exist
```

EDIT 2

```
>> ls /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae*

/dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae
```

.

```
>> blkid /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae*

(empty result)
```

Comment: Probably you should try mounting it using offset as system didn't create block devices for partitions. Check this question please https://superuser.com/questions/1173600/how-to-mount-a-partition-by-specifying-block-range-instead-of-partition-on-linux

Comment: Thanks, the partition is recognized with command >> mount -o offset=$((512*204802048)) /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae /mnt/varie/

Comment: so did you mount it successfully?

Comment: yes, mounted succesfully

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you do not mount a volume (filesystem), but a whole disk. Try this:

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae-part5 /mnt/varie/
```

Comment: Not working... 

special device /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae-part5 does not exist

Comment: Could you show us the output of the following commands? `ls /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae*` and `blkid /dev/mapper/pdc_bcbfiijhae*`?

Comment: In the EDIT 2 ..